# Trying to show that if sup f(x) = inf f(x), then the function f is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

**If $\sup f(x)$ = $\inf f(x)$, then the function f is continuous.**

**where [a,$x_{{0}}$) and ($x_{{0}}$,b]**

For a nondecreasing function, given a point $x_{{0}}$ on an interval $[a,b]$, how am I supposed to show that, for each extrema (i.e. $\inf f(x)$) that this gives continuity?

I know that by definition of continuity, $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ iff for every $ε > 0$ there is a $δ > 0$ such that $|c-x| < δ$  $→$ $|f(c) - f(x)| < ε$.

Do I have to show continuity for each extrema via an epsilon-delta proof? I cannot initially assume continuity though.

Comment: Please define what you mean  by $\sup f(x)$.

Comment: Supremum = greatest lower bound of a function f(x).

Comment: Consider the function $f$ that is $1$ at $0$ and $0$ elsewhere. What is $\inf f(x)$ and what is $\sup f(x)$?

Comment: Correct me if I am being totally stupid -- if $\sup f=\inf f$ isn't $f$ constant?

Comment: @JackyChong supf(x) = 1 and inf f(x) = 0

Comment: What I'm trying to say is your definition is incorrect. You are taking sup and inf over a one point set.

Comment: That is why I am confused as to show how sup f(x) = inf f(x) at a point x0 on an interval [a,b] could imply continuity.

Comment: There is a theorem that says "f is continuous at x∈[a,b] if and only if sup f(x) = inf f(x) for a nondecreasing function f: [a,b] --> R."

I am trying to show one of the conditionals of the if and only if.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to the contrary that $f(x)$ is not continuous at a point $c$ in $[a,b]$. Then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$
there exists an $x\in [a,b]$ such that $|x - c| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(c)| \geq \epsilon$. Without restricting generality,
suppose that $x > c$ for some $\delta > 0$. Since $f$ is nondecreasing it follows that $\sup f \geq f(x) \geq \epsilon + f(c) > f(c) \geq \inf f$,
which contradicts that $\sup f = \inf f$.